# What is RadioShack 276-0326?

Tags: phototransistor, photoresistor, photosensor

It says it is an ambient light sensor, but is it a phototransistor? Something else? It has Vcc and Vout pins. Bonus points if you include a data sheet.

[image: back of package]

Comment: Yeah you'll want to go to digikey where you can actually see the datasheet for what you are buying. Radioshack used to just mix up a bunch of random crap (PNP transistors - great thanks) for people that have way too much time on their hands. Digikey or mouser is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this one?

[ALS-PDT243-3C/L451 Ambient Light Sensor 5mm T-1](http://www.everlight.com/file/ProductFile/ALS-PDT243-3C-L451.pdf)

> The ALS-PDT243-3C/L451 is an ambient light sensor using a photo transistor in a DIP package.

Comment: Close enough, so I accept it

Answer (score 0):

It's a phototransistor. Here's a link to it (5-pack): http://comingsoon.radioshack.com/radioshack-5mm-ambient-light-sensor-5-pack/2760326.html

No datasheet though.

Comment: ... which brings us to the **cardinal rule:**  *No datasheet ⇒ No sale*

Comment: What, `Lower dark current: 0.1uA` isn't good enough for you? ;)